# abstraction layers (OS, data types)

Tags: c, abstraction

Normally PAL (Platform Abstraction Layer) attempts to abstract I/O, synchronization primitives, socket calls etc. provided by an underlying operating system.

Now, my question is about data types which can be different across hardware platforms, are those also maintained by PAL, or this is responsibility of another abstractation layer, e.g. HAL?

For instance, the same OS may be running on two different CPUs with 16-bit or 32-bit ints.

I understand that data types are determined by compilers, but often we need to have 'standard' names of types, e.g. pal_int16.

How can this be handled correctly from the point of view of abstraction layers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, my question is about data types which can be different across
>   hardware platforms, are those also maintained by PAL, or this is
>   responsibility of another abstractation layer, e.g. HAL?

I do not think we have a strict definition about what PAL is. So, it's up to the programmer to decide where to include type definition functions.

If there are some type operations, that are not by some reason handled by a compiler and the standard library, then, I think you can by all means include those into PAL as a separate module. Why not?